# How to verify if 'aria-disabled' attribute is present in an element or not using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

HTML of the button.

```
<div id="MainTab" aria-disabled='true'>
```

when button is not clickable, `aria-disabled = 'true'` as:

```
<div id="MainTab" aria-disabled='true'>
```

when button is clickable, `aria-disabled` is not present as:

```
<div id="MainTab">
```

How to write a code to identify whether `aria-disabled` attribute is present or not in:

```
<div id="MainTab" ...>
```

The element "MainTab" is always visible.

"aria-disabled" is true, "MainTab" is disabled, not clickable

"aria-disabled" is false, "MainTab" is enabled and clickable

How do I use `wait.until()` to probe either "MainTab" is disabled or clickable? The purpose is to probe when "MainTab" is clickable, then execute

```
FindElement(By.Id("MainTab")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<div id="MainTab" aria-disabled="true">
```

To probe if the attribute [*`aria-disabled`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-disabled) is present or not you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CssSelector*:

  ```
  IWebElement Element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div#MainTab[aria-disabled]"));
  ```
- Using *XPath*:

  ```
  IWebElement Element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='MainTab' and @aria-disabled]"));
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  

Now I can get: string temp = driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainTab")).GetAttribute("aria-disabled");

The element "MainTab" is alawys visible.  

"aria-disabled" is ture, "MainTab" is disabled, not clickable
"aria-disabled" is false, "MainTab" is enabled, and clickable

How to use wait.until to probe either "MainTab" is disable or clickale? 

Or use wait.until(ToString) to get when "aria-disabled" is false? 

The purpose is to probe when "MainTab" is clickable, then execute

FindElement(By.Id("MainTab")).click();

Comment: I do not how to add comments with the proper format. I pasted my comments under my original questions under: 2023-Mar-07

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to use `.GetAttribute("aria-disabled")` on the element to return the value.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
string ariaDisabled = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("MainTab"))).GetAttribute("aria-disabled");
```

| ariaDisabled | HTML |
| --- | --- |
| "true" | `<div id="MainTab" aria-disabled='true'>` |
| "" | `<div id="MainTab">` |

If it were me and I was going to use this more than once, I would put it in a function, e.g.

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines if the specified element has the aria-disabled attribute
/// </summary>
/// <param name="locator">The locator of the desired element</param>
/// <returns>A tuple of the element and a bool as true if the element has the aria-disabled attribute, false otherwise.</returns>
public (IWebElement, bool) IsAriaDisabled(By locator)
{
    IWebElement e = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(locator));
    return (e, "true" == e.GetAttribute("aria-disabled"));
}
```

and then you call it like

```
(IWebElement e, bool isAriaDisabled) = IsAriaDisabled(By.Id("MainTab1"));
if (isAriaDisabled)
{
    Console.WriteLine("'MainTab' is disabled, not clickable");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("'MainTab' is enabled and clickable");
    e.Click();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not know how to reply your answer in the proper format. I added my further question in my original question under 2023-Mar-06.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your comment